# Question on time hierarchy

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes, oracle-machines

How can I prove that $\mathsf{DTIME}^{\mathrm{Htm}}(n^2)$ is contained in $\mathsf{DTIME}^{\mathrm{Htm}}(n^3)$?

(sorry about how it is written. I mean the set of languages decided by a deterministic TM with an oracle to $\mathrm{Htm}$ in $n^2$ time and $n^3$ time).

If someone can please write the proof, it will be great.

Comment: What do you mean by Htm?

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear: Htm still hasn't been defined and the asker has been absent from the site for nearly a month.

Answer (score 1):

A language is in $\mathsf{DTIME}(f(n))$ if there is a Turing machine accepting the language and running in time *at most* $f(n)$ (or, in some definitions, $O(f(n))$). Therefore $f(n) \leq g(n)$ implies that $\mathsf{DTIME}(f(n)) \subseteq \mathsf{DTIME}(g(n))$. The same holds for relativized classes.

Comment: Thanks!
I missed a small detail in the question which makes it different... I meant contained but not equal :)

Comment: This is the well-known time hierarchy theorem. Wikipedia contains a proof.

Comment: @koral Please edit your question to include that crucial information, as well as the definition of "Htm".